# Array Operations in MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I am trying to convert a snippet of MATLAB code to python. The MATLAB code is

```
    for o = 1:orient            
        for s = 1:scale

            M(:,:,s) = ifft2(imfft .* filter{s,o});

            s_lc(:,:,o) = s_lc(:,:,o).*(M(:,:,s).^w(s));

        end

    end
```

Where,
    orient = 8, 
    scale = 3, 
    w = [1, -3, 2], 
    imfft = imfft2(image), 
    'filter' is a cell array with matrix elements, each matrix is of the size of 'image'

I have written an equivalent code in python, which looks like,

```
for o in range(orient):
    for s in range(scale):
        M[:,:,s] = np.fft.ifft2 (imfft * filter[s][o])
        s_lc[:,:,o] = (s_lc[:,:,o])*((M[:,:,s])**w[s])
```

here all the input variables hold the same save values as of MATLAB. But the value of s_lc is not as the same of MATLAB after the complete iterations.

Can somebody help me with replicating the same functionality of MATLAB in Python for the above snippet of code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is perfectly correct. However, MATLAB and numpy express multi-dimensional arrays differently. If you are using rank-3 arrays, compare `s_lc[i,j,k]` of python and `s_lc(i+1,j+1,k+1)` of MATLAB element-by-element.